# Why are users' PINs not accepted at Windows' "Your pin is required to log in" prompt?

Tags: windows, authentication, password

Windows Hello says "Your PIN is required to sign in.
But when users enter their pin it is not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The system continues to prompt "Your PIN is required to sign in" when it really wants the password. Try entering the password instead.